# How to get and update last string after some character like '\ ' in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

How to split `df['FullString']` and get the last phrase after `'\'` then update to `df['Splitted']`?

df:

```
FullString                          Splitted
2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\0123456789    0123456789
2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\25632589      25632589
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that can be done easily like this:

```
df['Splitted'] = [s.split('\\')[-1] for s in df['FullString']]
print(df)
```

output:

```
                         FullString    Splitted
0  2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\0123456789  0123456789
1    2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\25632589    25632589
```

PS:

you can start with only `FullString` column like this one:

```
                         FullString
0  2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\0123456789
1    2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\25632589
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer if it suited your needs for future users

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorised [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html#pandas.Series.str.rsplit) to achieve this:

```
In[81]:
df['Splitted'] = df['FullString'].str.rsplit('\\').str[-1]
df

Out[81]: 
                         FullString   Splitted  
0  2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\0123456789  0123456789   
1    2\0\2\0\R\A\T\I\O\0\0\25632589   25632589
```